When is a surface with a metric $g$ of modified covariant Hessian type?
A surface $(M^2,g)$ is said to be of (locally) Hessian type when there exists coordinates $(x^1,x^2)$ such that there exists a function $f(x^1,x^2)$ satisfying
$$g = \frac{\partial^2 f}{dx^i dx^j} dx^i dx^j\,.$$
It is known that all surfaces (with smooth or analytic metric $g$) are locally Hessian - this is discussed here.
Of interest for a problem I am considering is what can be said about modifications of the (locally) Hessian condition. For example, consider the following differential equation:
$$[\partial_i \partial_j - \Omega^{-2} \delta_{ij} (d \log \Omega)^k \partial_k + 2 (d \log \Omega)_{(i} \partial_{j)}] f = T_{ij}\,,$$
where $T$ is some non-degenerate symmetric tensor, $\Omega$ is a positive function, and indices are raised with $\Omega^2 \delta^{ij}$. It seems (from my fairly naive eyes) that some of the arguments that ensure a surface is locally Hessian (found here) only depend on the symbol of the differential operator, but I am unsure of this.
For context, this differential equation arises from isothermal coordinates on a surface, which always exist locally. For context, I am really interested in the existence of solutions around a point to the equation
$$\nabla^2 h = T\,,$$
for some non-degenerate $T$. If there is an alternative way to see when this differential equation has solutions, that would also be acceptable.
So, the question is: what is known about existence of solutions to these equations? When does there exist an $h$ such these equations have solutions? What obstructs the existence of solutions, if there is not always a solution?

In your modified equation, what is $\Omega$?  What is the relation between the indices $i$ and $j$ on the left and $a$ and $b$ on the right?  Also, what do you mean by $\bar\nabla$ in your second equation?

Here, $\Omega$ is just the conformal factor to get to a conformally-flat metric. But viewed independently of where it came from, we can consider it just as some positive function on the surface. The difference in indices is a typo - sorry about that! And $\bar{\nabla}$ is just meant to be the Levi-Civita connection. Sorry about the unusual notation! I have edited the question to be more clear.

I think that my answer to the MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123633/characterizing-hessians-among-symmetric-bilinear-tensors/123644#123644 answers your question about when a symmetric 2-tensor $T$ is the Hessian with respect to a given metric $g$ of some function $h$.  There are linear compatibility conditions (using a given metric $g$) that one computes for $T$.  These are spelled out in my answer.  If your question is "When does there exist a metric $g$ and a function $h$ for which $\nabla^2h = T$?", the answer would be different.
